# raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add users app which i made separately and then trying to add this to my blog. But the problem is every time i try to add this something is messed up like this error i am getting now.

> raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
>   django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>
> so far i have done this
>
> blog/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from users.views import login_view, register_view, logout_view

# from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
# from users import views as user_views
from posts.views import index,postDetail, categoryDetail, blog, search

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name="home"),
    path('blog/', blog, name="blog"),
    path('search/', search, name='search'),
    path('<slug>/', postDetail, name='post-detail'),
    path('category/<slug>/', categoryDetail, name='category-detail'),
    path('login/', login_view),
    path('logout/', logout_view),
    path('register/', register_view),
    # path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    # path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    # path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls'))
]
```

> settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

> users/forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth import (
        authenticate,
        get_user_model
    )
    User = get_user_model()

    class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField()
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
            username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

            if username and password:
                user = authenticate(username = username, password=password)
                if not user: 
                    raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exits')
                if not user.check_password(password):
                    raise forms.ValidationError('Incorrect Password')
                if not user.is_active:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('This user is not active')
            return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(label='Email Address')
        email2 = forms.EmailField(label= 'Confirm Email')
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields =[
                'username',
                'email',
                'email2',
                'password'
            ]

        def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
            if email != email2:
                raise forms.ValidationError('email must match')
            eamil_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if eamil_qs.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "This email is already being used"
                )
            return super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

> users/views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login, 
    logout
)

from .forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegisterForm
# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username= username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if next: 
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def register_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username= user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next: 
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/login')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
```

This url is commented out, and you do not have any others with `name="login"`.

Comment: I thought this one is used only when you are using class based view thats why i commented this and made new one using only functional based view.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given name to your login url,

```
path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
```